# How to give a specific pyqt program read/write permission?

Tags: permissions, sudo, pyqt

I'm using a program called gnuradio-companion. If I start it without root privileges, I can't save anything because I don't have read/write privileges. It gives:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/FileDialogs.py:102: GtkWarning: Failed to read filechooser settings from "/home/nick/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini": Permission denied
```

If I start it with

```
sudo gnuradio-companion
```

then I'm abusing sudo, and also I get

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

because I lose the runtime variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. I can use

```
sudo -E
```

to preserve environment variables but then I get

```
QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0
```

I guess because I'm just borrowing root privileges. Using sudo visudo to modify runtime environments gives the same thing.

How should I configure read/write privileges and run time environments to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you should not run graphical programs as root in the first place...

Run

```
sudo chown nick:nick /home/nick/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini
```

to restore ownership of the configuration file. This of course assumes that the username is `nick`

You may want to do this recursively for all of `~/.config`

```
sudo chown -R nick:nick /home/nick/.config/
```

Comment: Lesson learned. To clarify, file permissions got messed up because the first time I ran was with root privileges, causing the config file to be owned by root and not user.